# How to ClickOnce install DLL locally instead of GAC

Tags: clickonce, gac

My app uses DevExpress DLL's which are installed in the GAC. Is it possible to let ClickOnce install the required DLL's in the local directories instead of GAC? I know ClickOnce cannot do anything with the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you deply the DevExpress assemblies your application needs in the same directory as the application you don't need the GAC.